# thumbnail creation crashes in easy_thumbnails.processors.background

Tags: django, easy-thumbnails

I am using Django and easy-thumbnails 2.3. My intention is to take an image, scale it down so that it fits a square and fill the empty area with white color in case of non-square original images. Also in case of transparent images the transparency shall be changed to white.

My settings.py contains the following lines:

```
THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.colorspace',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.autocrop',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.scale_and_crop',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.filters',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.background',
)

THUMBNAIL_ALIASES = {
    '':{            
        'square_image': {'background':'#fff','replace_alpha':'#fff','size':(200,200)},
        },
    }

THUMBNAIL_TRANSPARENCY_EXTENSION = 'jpg'
```

I've tried some debugging and everything seems to work quite well and makes sense until the code reaches a line 318 in the background-processor function of easy-thumbnails `processors.py`:

```
im = colorspace(im, replace_alpha=background, **kwargs)
```

Here the debugger returns straight to the method that was calling `background(im, size, background=None, **kwargs)`.

Is there anything wrong with my configuration of `square_image` in THUMBNAIL_ALIASES? Could it be anything else?

Comment: Show the full stacktrace.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev , thanks! I tried to figure out how to get the stacktrace and realized that there was a "fail silently" option. I've figured the problem out and will write an answer. I'll upvote your comment for pushing me in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can't use `'background':'#fff'` from the background processor and `'replace_alpha':'#fff'` from the colorspace processor at the same time, as the `background`-key is turned into `replace_alpha` in

```
im = colorspace(im, replace_alpha=background, **kwargs)
```

and then you end up with two `replace_alpha`, as one is still in `**kwargs`. This causes the error. But it also turns out that in

```
THUMBNAIL_ALIASES = {
    '':{            
        'square_image': {'background':'#fff','replace_alpha':'#fff','size':(200,200)}, #wrong
        },
    }
```

you don't even need `replace_alpha`. The background processor does not add bars at the sides of a non-fitting image, but instead the image gets written on a - in my case white - background. The colorspace conversion does not seem to happen before that. So the proper definition would be

```
THUMBNAIL_ALIASES = {
    '':{            
        'square_image': {'background':'#fff','size':(200,200)},
        },
    }
```